# How to get the items object without the tabs in a TabPanel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I would like to loop through items of a TabPanel without the Tabs (which are not defined in the class, but are added by the framework dynamically).
here is the relevant code :

```
Ext.define('MyTabPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

    config:{
        height: '50px',
        autoDestroy : true,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'item',
            },{
                xtype: 'item',
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

When I loop through the items with the each function, it also loops through the tabs :

```
ext-item-1 
ext-tabbar-1 
ext-item-2 
ext-item-3 
ext-tabbar-2 
ext-item-4
```

Is there a function to omit these hidden sneaky tabs ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`getInnerItems`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-method-getInnerItems) method to receive only items which are not docked to the tabpanel or floating.

```
var items = tabPanel.getInnerItems();
```

Also see this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5qi)

Comment: This works for this case, but I guess there is no real function to get only the items the programmer actually defined ?

I chose to add a test before appying my logic to each items to see if it's an instance of tabbar or not. Would have been neat if it was in the framework though.

Comment: For a tab panel this will work in all cases. I **assume** you can safely use this with other components as well, as I doubt that they'd actually add items to the innerItems array themselves.

Comment: If I add a component docked in the items, it won't be returned right ?